# Connections between the randomness of the normal distribution and Textrank?

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chains, random, page-rank

In a TED speech [on 8:40](https://www.ted.com/talks/cedric_villani_what_s_so_sexy_about_math/transcript?language=en#t-511484) the mathematician said that:

> This algorithm uses the laws of mathematical randomness to determine
>   automatically the most relevant web pages, in the same way as we used
>   randomness in the Galton Board experiment.

[image]

I want to bridge the gap between these two kinds of randomness in my mind. Or how can I interpret TextRank or PageRank in a statistical way? Could anyone please help?

I have read this tutorial: [TextRank: Bringing order into texts](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2004/emnlp/pdf/Mihalcea.pdf) and have a basic understanding of the TextRank algorithm. So far as I know TextRank can be viewed as a Markov chain, but can we see what happens in Galton Board experiment also a Markov chain? Or how can we represent what happen in the Galton Board experiment and the experiment in the above picture in mathematical language?